# How do I pray the missing Salah

Tags: salat

My question is how do I pray the *Salah* that I have been missing?

I know its a sin if one don't pray his *Salah* on time and he have to ask for forgiveness but after that, how do I pray my *Qadha Salah*?

I have missed my *Salah* for many years and it would be very difficult if I have to make the *Qadha* of every *Salah* that I missed.

1. Do my *Niyyah* be like: "I make *Niyyah* for the first *Duhr Salah* that I have have missed" and so on, and pray them in the order I missed them; first *Fajr* that I missed, then *Duhr* I missed and then *Asar* I missed.....
2. Or Can I just say "I make *Niyyah* for the *Qadha Duhr*" and pray my 3-4 *Qadha Duhr* prayers one after another with seperate *Niyyah*?

Do I have to pray them in the correct order and make the *Niyyah* with the of number the *Qadha Salah* I am offering?

Comment: For the ease of offering Kaza Salat, you can calculate and perform them with an App. http://bit.ly/KazaSalat It does show the calculation method and allows to keep track of Kaza Salat.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you have answered the question yourself:

> Do my Niyyah be like: "I make Niyyah for the first Duhr Salah that I have have missed" and so on, and pray them in the order I missed them; first Fajr that I missed, then Duhr I missed and then Asar I missed.....

This is the proper way of making Neeyiah of praying missed Salah. 
You could start by praying extra Fard with after every Salah you pray.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

First it is not obligatory for niyah to be verbal. all what you need is to know that you are praying the missed salah:

> Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Actions are but by intentions, and everyone shall have but that which he intended…”
>
> > Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1; Muslim, 1907

The correct order is obligatory for the prayers that are in the same day. For example you can't pray Asur then Duhr for the same day nor you can pray isha'a before maghrib (for the same day).

[Source](http://www.najaf.org/?lang=arabic&tab=ara_link&cat=learn&id=l_qadha)